# Fluid sim problem: fluid growing in volume

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to generate a small amount of water in a clear bottle, then pour the water out of the bottle. It's all going well, except that from the moment the water collides, it starts to grow and grow until it's filling the bottle, then tapers off until it finally all pours out. I'm starting with a small fluid object less than 1/10 the volume of the bottle, but it seems like every collision causes the fluid to double! I'm not using outflow, and it's not a problem with failing to apply scale. What am I doing wrong?
I've been trying to solve this on and off for months!
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: I can try. Where?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/658/599

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=601" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/601/)

Comment: Did that work? I'm finding it a little confusing, I'll admit

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really get my head around what's going on in your blend file, but the basics of the fluid sim are all wrong. The domain should not have any key framed properties, and yes, scale should be applied.

My guess is that since the euler scale of the domain is off, the impact value of the obstacle (the bottle) gets calculated as if it was greater than 1. Decreasing the impact value decreases the problem you have, but really, the fluid sim should be set up properly.